# Query string not retrieving data values

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Hope you guys could give me some help.

I have a asp.net web form which gets data from SQL database and displays it on webpage via product code number or product description.
Searching by description will display a list of similar products where each list will have a button with the product code when clicked will open another site with extra product information,

e.g.
13892
14589
17485
00010
08890

The problem is all the codes that start from 1 upwards will show more details, but when I click on product codes that start with 0 such as 00010, 08890 will show no data when in fact there should be data.

Any help would be appreciated.

code I have below,

```
  Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Val(Request.QueryString("Stock_code")) <> 0 Then

        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable

        Dim strQuery As String = "SELECT STKCODE as [Stock_Code], STKNAME as [Stock_Description], STK_BASEPRICE as [Retail_Price], STK_SORT_KEY2 as [Pack_Size], STK_NOTES as [Notes], STK_P_WEIGHT as [Net_Weight], STK_S_WEIGHT as [Gross_Weight] FROM dbo.STK_STOCK WHERE STKCODE = '" & Val(Request.QueryString("Stock_code")) & "'"

        Dim strQUery2 As String = "SELECT LOC_CODE as [Location_Code], LOC_NAME as [Location], LOC_PHYSICAL as [Physical_Stock] FROM dbo.STK_LOCATION WHERE LOC_CODE IN ('WH01','WH03','WH04','WH08','WH11')" & _
              "AND LOC_STOCK_CODE = '" & Val(Request.QueryString("Stock_code")) & "'"

        Dim strQuery3 As String = "SELECT STKLANG_STOCKNAME as [Chinese_Description] FROM dbo.STK_STOCK_LANG WHERE STKLANG_STOCKCODE ='" & Val(Request.QueryString("stock_code")) & "'"


        Dim strQuery4 = "SELECT STK_SELLPRICE1 as [Retail_Price], STK_SELLPRICE5 as [Retail_Rest_Split] FROM dbo.STK_STOCK_2 WHERE STKCODE2 = '" & Val(Request.QueryString("stock_code")) & "'"


        Using cmd4 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(strQuery4)
            Dim da3 As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter
            Dim dt4 As New DataTable
            cmd4.Connection = cnn : cnn.Open()
            da3.SelectCommand = cmd4
            da3.Fill(dt4)
            For i = 0 To dt4.Rows.Count - 1

                Label8.Text = dt4.Rows(i).Item("Retail_Rest_Split")

            Next
        End Using
        cnn.Close()


        Using cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(strQuery)
            Dim sda As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter

            cmd.Connection = cnn : cnn.Open()
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd
            sda.Fill(dt)

            For i = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1


                Label7.Text = dt.Rows(i).Item("Stock_Code")

                Label1.Text = dt.Rows(i).Item("Notes")
                Label3.Text = dt.Rows(i).Item("Retail_Price")
                Label4.Text = dt.Rows(i).Item("Pack_Size")
                Label5.Text = dt.Rows(i).Item("Stock_Description")

                'Label8.Text = dt.Rows(i).Item("Pack_Size")

                Label9.Text = dt.Rows(i).Item("Net_Weight")
                Label10.Text = dt.Rows(i).Item("Gross_Weight")

                GridView1.DataSource = dt
                GridView1.DataBind()
            Next
        End Using
        cnn.Close()

        Dim dt3 As DataTable = New DataTable
        Using cmd3 As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand(strQuery3)
            Dim da2 As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter


            cmd3.Connection = cnn : cnn.Open()
            da2.SelectCommand = cmd3
            da2.Fill(dt3)
        End Using

        For i = 0 To dt3.Rows.Count - 1
            Label6.Text = dt3.Rows(i).Item("Chinese_Description")
        Next

        Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand
        Dim dt2 As New DataTable
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
        With cmd2
            .Connection = cnn
            .CommandText = strQUery2
        End With

        da.SelectCommand = cmd2
        da.Fill(dt2)
        GridView1.DataSource = dt2
        GridView1.DataBind()

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I bet your `Val` function is turning your string into a number, and please please please use SQL Parameters

Comment: How should I amend this?

Comment: If your StockCode is as string, it won't work.  Val converts the value to a numeric value (Double or Decimal, I don't remember which), and if it can't parse as a number, returns 0.   If you take that out it will work, but then you open yourself to SQL injection.  To see what I mean, try this as a stock code parameter and see what happens:   anything' or '1'='1

Comment: More malicious example (think about what this would do but do NOT execute it):  '; DROP TABLE dbo.STK_STOCK_2 --

Comment: @dwilliss Unfortunately doesn't work. I removed the stock code query string  and also added '=1' which displays nothing at all even for codes beginning 1+ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use a paramaterized query like this (I'm going to fold that query string to make it more readable without having to scroll horizontally):

```
Dim strQuery As String = "SELECT STKCODE as [Stock_Code], STKNAME as [Stock_Description], 
               STK_BASEPRICE as [Retail_Price], STK_SORT_KEY2 as 
               [Pack_Size], STK_NOTES as [Notes], STK_P_WEIGHT as 
               [Net_Weight], STK_S_WEIGHT as [Gross_Weight] FROM 
               dbo.STK_STOCK WHERE STKCODE = @StockCode"

Using cmd As New SqlCommand(strQuery)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StockCode", Request.QueryString("Stock_code"))

    ' Do your other stuff here.
End Using
```

Note, that you don't want to just use string concatenation to insert your query parameter.  That opens you up to [SQL injection attacks](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection).

Instead, you use a placeholder in your query like @StockCode.  Then you call AddWithValue on the command to give it the value of that parameter.

You can also explicitly specify the parameter type if you need to:

```
    ' Add CustomerID parameter for WHERE clause.
    command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int)
    command.Parameters("@ID").Value = customerID
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they are all 5 digit codes, this will make sure the stock code is numeric.

Replace

```
Val(Request.QueryString("Stock_code"))
```

with

```
String.Format("{0:00000}", Integer.Parse(Request.QueryString("Stock_code")))
```

Will raise an exception if `Request.QueryString("Stock_code")` is not parsed as integer, which prevents against malicious injection.

For example:

```
Dim stockCode = String.Format("{0:00000}", Integer.Parse(Request.QueryString("Stock_code")))

Dim strQuery As String = "SELECT STKCODE as [Stock_Code], STKNAME as [Stock_Description], STK_BASEPRICE as [Retail_Price], STK_SORT_KEY2 as [Pack_Size], STK_NOTES as [Notes], STK_P_WEIGHT as [Net_Weight], STK_S_WEIGHT as [Gross_Weight] FROM dbo.STK_STOCK WHERE STKCODE = '" & stockCode & "'"
Dim strQUery2 As String = "SELECT LOC_CODE as [Location_Code], LOC_NAME as [Location], LOC_PHYSICAL as [Physical_Stock] FROM dbo.STK_LOCATION WHERE LOC_CODE IN ('WH01','WH03','WH04','WH08','WH11')" & "AND LOC_STOCK_CODE = '" & stockCode & "'"
Dim strQuery3 As String = "SELECT STKLANG_STOCKNAME as [Chinese_Description] FROM dbo.STK_STOCK_LANG WHERE STKLANG_STOCKCODE ='" & stockCode & "'"
Dim strQuery4 = "SELECT STK_SELLPRICE1 as [Retail_Price], STK_SELLPRICE5 as [Retail_Rest_Split] FROM dbo.STK_STOCK_2 WHERE STKCODE2 = '" & stockCode & "'"
```

@dwilliss has just answered the question using parameters, which is probably better than my method. Posting this anyway

Comment: Just realised that stock code is a varchar data type.

Comment: Just tried your method but get the error message 'value cannot be null'

Comment: What value is null?

Comment: Well if `Request.QueryString("Stock_code")` is returning a string, it probably has the correct format already. You may not need any validation at all. Is that method even prone to injection? You may just be able to use `Request.QueryString("Stock_code")` by itself. My method just makes sure it's a valid 5 digit integer (and keeps it formatted that way) before running the query.

Comment: error highlights the code 'String.Format("{0:00000}", Integer.Parse(Request.QueryString("Stock_code")))'

Comment: What is the value of `Request.QueryString("Stock_code")` at this time?

Comment: With the current code at    'If Val(Request.QueryString("Stock_code")) <> 0 Then'. If I click on products 123,157,185,258, products info will show. However all product codes that start with 0 e.g. 0123, 01458,01254, will show nothing at all.
I am guessing that the starting zero are not being recognised.

Comment: Change it to this: `Dim stockCode = Request.QueryString("Stock_code")` then

Comment: Still the same problem

Comment: <asp:TemplateField HeaderText ="Code">
                      <ItemTemplate>
                      
                           <input type="button" 
                            class="btInGrid" value='<%# Eval("Stock_Code")%>' 
                            onclick='javascript:window.open("http://********/Info.aspx?Stock_Code=<%# Eval("Stock_Code")%>    " ,"Stone Details","height=700,width=600,status=yes,resizable=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=center,scrollbars=no,resizable=no")' />


                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

Comment: Looks like you have some basic debugging to do

Comment: The value comes from a grid view with product codes which are linked to the button.

Comment: Fine but you are using `Request.QueryString("Stock_code")` as your stock code so it has to evaluate to something at runtime. It looks like it should be a number formatted as a string. When you have an exception, I guess there's no number in it. But I can't debug for you. This is what you should be checking

Comment: It is set up as string because some product codes contains letters at the end.

Comment: Then my answer doesn't work, just use `Dim stockCode = Request.QueryString("Stock_code")`. If some codes have letters at the end, why were you using `Val()` in the first place? This returns a number from string but *zero if it can't be converted to a number* which is dangerous when you *expect* that some have letters at the end!

Comment: Apologies, just realised that some product codes had letters at the end.

Comment: You should think about your stop condition `If Val(Request.QueryString("Stock_code")) <> 0 Then`, is this right? What causes this to not be usable, i.e. create a situation where you *don't* want to continue? Empty value? null? Check it accordingly